# Pascal's Triangle via Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, pascals-triangle

Is my current code even possible? I have to create [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) with an input without using any loops. I am bound to recursion.

I have spent three days on this, and this is the best output that I can come up with.

```
def pascal(curlvl, newlvl, tri):

  if curlvl == newlvl:
    return ""

  else:

    tri.append(tri[curlvl])

    print(tri)
    return pascal(curlvl+1, newlvl, tri)


def triLvl():
  msg = "Please enter the number of levels to generate: "

  triheight = int(input(msg))

  if triheight < 1:
    print("\n Sorry, the number MUST be positive\n Please try again.")
    return triLvl()

  else:
    return triheight


def main():

   triangle = [1]

   curlvl = 0

   print("Welcome to the Pascal's triangle generator.")

   usrTri = triLvl()
   print(triangle)
   pascal(curlvl, usrTri, triangle)


main()
```

Comment: why is also ` triLvl()` recursive?

Comment: Just at a glance, I don't see an addition of recursive calls. The entry at triangle[row][column] = triangle[row-1][column] + triangle[row-1][column+1] (except at the boundaries where it's always 1.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/96211/pascals-triangle-recursion

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Specifically, what output do you get, what did you expect, and what have you done in diagnosing the problem?

Comment: What algorithm are you using to generate the triangle?  There's nothing in your code that can produce any integer except for 1: no accumulation, no addition, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define a recursive `pascal` using a helper function, `pairs`.

`pascal` will return `[[Int]]` (an array of arrays of Int). For example, `pascal(3)` would return

```
[ [1],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 2, 1] ]
```

OK, so I'll show you all the code up front, but then I'll step through and explain certain bits afterwards.

```
def pairs (xs):
  if 2 > len(xs):
    return []
  else:
    return [xs[0:2]] + pairs(xs[1:])

def pascal (n):
  def compute (prev):
    return [1] + [x + y for (x,y) in pairs(prev)] + [1]
  def aux (m, prev):
    if (m > n):
      return []
    else:
      return [prev] + aux(m + 1, compute(prev))
  return aux(1, [1])

[print(line) for line in pascal(5)]
# [1]
# [1, 1]
# [1, 2, 1]
# [1, 3, 3, 1]
# [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```

---

**Explanation**

What we really care about is the `pascal` function. Everything else we've written was born out of the way we write `pascal`, so I'll start by going over that.

A very common way to write recursive functions is to use an inner auxiliary function that keeps track of our computation's various states. We'll be using this technique as the basis of our `pascal` function.

```
def my_recursive_func (<parameters>):
  def aux (<state_parameters>):
    if (<base_condition>):
      return <base_value>
    else
      return aux(<updated_state>)
  return aux(<initial_state>)
```

We already know how to fill in some of this boilerplate for our `pascal` function:

- `parameters` should just be `n`, an Integer, because we expect to call our function like `pascal(3)` or `pascal(5)`, etc – no other arguments should be accepted
- `state_parameters` – we only know two things right now: 1) we will need some value `m` that counts up to `n`, incrementing by `1` each time – and 2) some value that allows us to compute the next row; we'll call it `prev` since each pascal row is computed based on the *previous* row
- `base_condition` – when `m == n` we know we've generated all the rows we need, this is when we want to stop recursing
- `base_value` – this is the last value returned – not quite sure what that should be yet
- `updated_state` – we will update `m` using `m + 1` and we will update the rows presumably using some kind of array concatenation – not exactly sure until we write more code
- `initial_state` – we will start `m` at `1` and the first row of pascal is `[1]`

OK, let's fill in what we have so far:

```
def pascal (n):
  def aux (m, prev):
    if (m > n):
      return ?
    else:
      return aux(m + 1, ?)
  return aux(1, [1])
```

We'd like to have `pascal` build our result something like this:

```
[[1]] + [[1, 1]] + [[1, 2, 1]] + [[1, 3, 3, 1]], ...]
# => [ [1], [1 ,1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], ... ]
```

So in order to write the `base_value` and updated state for `prev`, we need to consider this return *type*. We want to return `[[Int]]`, which is a list, so the  `base_value` can simply be the empty list, `[]`.

That means in each step, we actually want to take `[prev]` and concatenate (`+`) it to the recursive result as well ...

```
[prev] + aux(m + 1, <next_row>)
```

We're getting really close now. Let's update `pascal` again to see what we have to finish up:

```
def pascal (n):
  def aux (m, prev):
    if (m > n):
      return []
    else:
      return [prev] + aux(m + 1, <next_row>)
  return aux(1, [1])
```

Ok, so here comes the hard part – calculating the next row, right? Well, it's not too bad actually.

```
# Given
[1,2,1]

# the next row is
[1, (1 + 2), (2 + 1), 1]
```

Or another example

```
# Given
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]

# the next row is
[1, (1 + 4), (4 + 6), (6 + 4), (4 + 1), 1]
```

So the pattern is something like this: Create a new array starting with `1`, then for each pair of numbers in the previous row, add the two numbers together and append each sum to the array, then finally append another `1`. We might express that in Python like using a list comprehension like this:

```
[1] + [x + y for (x,y) in pairs(prev)] + [1]
```

Now we just need to figure out that `pairs` function. `pairs` should have the following contract:

```
pairs([])        => []
pairs([a])       => []
pairs([a,b])     => [[a,b]]
pairs([a,b,c])   => [[a,b],[b,c]]
pairs([a,b,c,d]) => [[a,b],[b,c],[c,d]]
```

Let's implement it now and verify that our implementation fulfills the contract. Note, I'm implementing this function *outside* of `pascal`, because it's a generic function and useful on its own. To compute pascal rows, we need to add pairs of numbers, but adding or *how* we get those pairs or numbers should not be left as a responsibility for the `pascal` function itself.

```
def pairs (xs):
  if 2 > len(xs):
    return []
  else:
    return [xs[0:2]] + pairs(xs[1:])

print(pairs([]))        # []
print(pairs([1]))       # []
print(pairs([1,2]))     # [[1,2]]
print(pairs([1,2,3]))   # [[1,2],[2,3]]
print(pairs([1,2,3,4])) # [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
```

OK, that's getting us really close now. Let's update the `pascal` function again to see where we're at:

```
def pascal (n):
  def aux (m, prev):
    if (m > n):
      return []
    else:
      return [prev] + aux(m + 1, [1] + [x + y for (x,y) in pairs(prev)] + [1])
  return aux(1, [1])
```

Holy smokes! We're already done. That `aux` call with the inline computation of the next row looks a little busy though. Let's add another helper inside `pascal` called `compute` to clean things up. Now we're done!

```
def pascal (n):
  def compute (prev):
    return [1] + [x + y for (x,y) in pairs(prev)] + [1]
  def aux (m, prev):
    if (m > n):
      return []
    else:
      return [prev] + aux(m + 1, compute(prev))
  return aux(1, [1])
```

---

**Being thorough**

If you want that goofy text and prompts to display, you can write `main` something like below. This keeps all the I/O separate from our `pascal` and `pairs` functions. This [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and managing of side effects is important to consider early in your program, because it's difficult to reuse functions that do more than we want them to.

```
def main ():
  try:
    print("Pascal triangle generator")
    n = int(input("Pascal(x): x = "))
    if n < 1: raise
    [print(line) for line in pascal(n)]
  except:
    print("enter a non-zero positive integer")
    main()

# run program
main()
```

Go ahead and run `pascal(300)` or something for some impressive results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for but it works just fine:

```
from operator import add


def pascal(curlvl, newlvl, tri):
    if curlvl == newlvl:
        return ""
    elif curlvl == 0:
        tri.append(1)
        print (tri)
        return pascal(curlvl + 1, newlvl, tri)
    else:
        tmp = [1]
        rt = tri[:-1]
        rt.reverse()
        # print (map(add, rt, tri[:-1]))
        # In Python 3, map returns a generator.
        # Wrapping map in list makes this code compatible with
        # both Python 2 and 3
        tt = list(map(add, rt, tri[:-1]))
        if (len(tt) > 0):
            tmp.extend(tt)
        tmp.append(1)
        tri = tmp
        print (tri)
        return pascal(curlvl + 1, newlvl, tri)


def triLvl():
    msg = "Please enter the number of levels to generate:"

    triheight = int(input(msg))

    if triheight < 1:
        print("\n Sorry, the number MUST be positive\n Please try again.")
        return triLvl()

    else:
        return triheight


def main():
    triangle = [1]

    curlvl = 0

    print("Welcome to the Pascal's triangle generator.")

    usrTri = triLvl()
    print(triangle)
    pascal(curlvl, usrTri, triangle)


main()
```

Comment: *Why* does it work? What is the gist?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*

Answer (score 0):

Recursive Pascal's triangle as a list:

```
P = lambda h:(lambda x:x+[[x+y for x,y in zip(x[-1] + [0], [0] + x[-1])]])(P(h-1)) if h>1 else[[1]]
print(P(10))
```

I don't know if 'zip' and 'map' are considered as loops (they certainly contain loops).