# Pascal's triangle in python without using any loops

Tags: python, recursion, pascals-triangle

So I'm trying to implement a pascal's triangle that produces the following in python:

```
pascal_triangle(5) prints:
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

The problem is I'm trying to do it without using any type of loops but can't figure out how to do that. Any help would be appreciated. Than you.

This is what I have so far:

```
   def factorial(x):
            if x == 0:
                    return 1
            else: 
                    x * factorial(x - 1)

    def pascal_triangle(n):`
```

UPDATED:

```
print_pascal_line(r):
    if r == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        R = print_pascal_line(r-1)
        return 1 +
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pascals triangle with recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687857/pascals-triangle-with-recursion)

Answer (score 2):

Each element of Pascal's triangle is evaluated using the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). This value, often referred to as `nCr`, asks "given `n` items how many ways can you `C`hoose `r` things?"

Take, for example, the items `a`, `b`, and `c`. How many ways can we create combinations of the following sizes?

0. There's only 1 way to choose 0 items: `{}`
1. There are 3 possible combinations: `{a}`, `{b}`, or `{c}`
2. Again, 3 ways: `{a, b}`, `{a, c}`, or `{b, c}`
3. Only `{a, b, c}`

And what would you know, that just so happens to be level 3* of Pascal's triangle: `1 3 3 1`! As it turns out, we can use this on every level.

```
0: nCr(0, 0)
1: nCr(1, 0) nCr(1, 1)
2: nCr(2, 0) nCr(2, 1) nCr(2, 2)
3: nCr(3, 0) nCr(3, 1) nCr(3, 2) nCr(3, 3)
etc
etc
```

So, how can we code for this? Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4941932/5491375) we get our `nCr` function

```
In [454]: import functools as ft

In [455]: import operator as op

In [456]: def nCr(n, r):
     ...:     r = min(r, n-r)
     ...:     numer = ft.reduce(op.mul, range(n, n - r, -1), 1)
     ...:     denom = ft.reduce(op.mul, range(1, r + 1), 1)
     ...:     return numer // denom
     ...:
```

Finally, let's make a recursive function to tie it all together.

```
In [457]: def pascal(n):
     ...:     if n >= 1:
     ...:         pascal(n - 1)
     ...:         print(' '.join(str(nCr(n - 1, r)) for r in range(n)))
     ...:

In [463]: pascal(5)
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

Technically, this is should be `pascal(4)` as Pascal's triangle is zero-indexed*, but I'm just going according to the OPs request. If we wanted to change this we would alter our `pascal` function to

```
In [468]: def pascal(n):
     ...:     if n >= 0:
     ...:         pascal(n - 1)
     ...:         print(' '.join(str(nCr(n, r)) for r in range(n + 1)))
     ...:
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I learned something new about Pascal. The `In [###]: ` prompts are distracting and make it difficult to copy/paste the code however.

Comment: The OP explicitly stated multiple times, "without using any loops".  The expression, `(str(nCr(n, r)) for r in range(n + 1))` is a loop!

Answer (score 1):

First create a function that prints the Nth line of the pascal triangle, and I advise you to use combinations instead of manually computing the values in each line using factorials, it would be much more efficient. Let's say this function is called print_pascal_line and receives an integer, the line number.

Then you just have:

```
def pascal_triangle(n):
    aux(0, n)

def aux(current_line, n):
    if current_line < n:
        print_pascal_line(current_line)
        aux(current_line + 1, n)
```

Or you can use default arguments to have this in one function only:

```
def pascal_triangle(n, current_line = 0):
    if current_line < n:
        print_pascal_line(current_line)
        pascal_triangle(n, current_line + 1)
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. here is my shot for the print_pascal_line: (and based on your explanation I believe this is only supposed to print that Nth line so for example if n=6, then it prints the 6th row) .

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. And by the way, here is something that will help you with your print_pascal_line function: [scipy.special.comb](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html#scipy.special.comb)

Answer (score 1):

A pure recursive solution (without loop, without assignment, without external modules, only python function used is `sum` which can be avoided as well). This code can be easily translated to LISP family language.

```
def pascal_line(n):
    def nextline(thisline):
        if thisline == []:
            return []
        else:
            return [sum(thisline[:2])] + nextline(thisline[1:])
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    elif n == 2:
        return [1, 1]
    else:
        return [1]+nextline(pascal_line(n-1))

def pascal_triangle(n):
    def printline(m):
        if m <= n:
            print(*pascal_line(m))
            printline(m+1)
    return printline(1)

pascal_triangle(6)
# output =>
# 1
# 1 1
# 1 2 1
# 1 3 3 1
# 1 4 6 4 1
# 1 5 10 10 5 1
```

Inner function `nextline` derives the next line (without leading 1) in pascal triangle based on current line recursively.

Function `pascal_line` derives the *nth* line in a pascal triangle, by calling `nextline` recursively with *(n-1)th* line (its own previous solution).

Function `pascal_triangle` prints out lines in pascal triangle by calling `pascal_line` recursively.

Three recursive functions all together nicely illustrated the typical divide and conquer nature of recursive approach.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def pascal_triangle(n, line=None):
    if n == 0: return
    if line is None: 
        line = [1]
    print(" ".join(map(str, line)))
    pascal_line(line)
    pascal_triangle(n-1, line)

def pascal_line(line, i=0, add=0):
    if i >= len(line):
        line.append(add)
        return
    add, line[i] = line[i], line[i] + add
    pascal_line(line, i+1, add)
```

Comment: this works aswell, however is there an alternate way of defining the parameters like line=None, i=0, and add=0, because I personally never learnt to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question once before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43689162/633183). Follow the link for an explanation of how to design recursive functions like this one.

```
def pairs (xs):
  if 2 > len(xs):
    return []
  else:
    return [xs[0:2]] + pairs(xs[1:])

def pascal (n):
  def compute (prev):
    return [1] + [x + y for (x,y) in pairs(prev)] + [1]
  def aux (m, prev):
    if (m > n):
      return []
    else:
      return [prev] + aux(m + 1, compute(prev))
  return aux(1, [1])

for line in pascal(5):
  print(line)
# [1]
# [1, 1]
# [1, 2, 1]
# [1, 3, 3, 1]
# [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```

Above we create a new `[1]` singleton in three places; two of which are part of the `compute` loop. We should create it once and reuse it instead.

```
def pascal (n):
  one = [1]
  def compute (prev):
    return one + [x + y for (x,y) in pairs(prev)] + one
  def aux (m, prev):
    if (m > n):
      return []
    else:
      return [prev] + aux(m + 1, compute(prev))
  return aux(1, one)
```

A final improvement I might suggest is to use a generator instead of returning all of the rows eagerly

```
def pascal (n):
  one = [1]
  def compute (prev):
    return one + [x + y for (x,y) in pairs(prev)] + one
  def aux (m, prev):
    if (m > n):
      return
    else:
      yield prev
      yield from aux(m + 1, compute(prev))
  yield from aux(1, one)
```

Now you can compute the output lazily, as it is consumed. If you want it all at once however, you can use `list`.

```
list(pascal(5))
# [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]]
```

Comment: very nice solution. we end up with almost same solution. I suggest to let `pairs` function return `[sum(xs[0:2])] + pairs(xs[1:])`. Then you save the list comprehension later in `compute` by returning `one + pairs(prev) + one` , which makes whole program more readable and concise and avoid any type of loop as requested by OP.

Comment: The OP explicitly stated multiple times, "without using any loops".  The expression, `[x + y for (x,y) in pairs(prev)]` is a loop!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler recursive solution that uses math to construct the triangle without any hidden loops:

```
def pascal(n, row=0):

    def pascal_row(numerator, denominator=1, number=1):
        if numerator > 0:
            number = number * numerator // denominator
            return [number, *pascal_row(numerator - 1, denominator + 1, number)]

        return []

    if row < n:
        return [[1, *pascal_row(row)], *pascal(n, row + 1)]

    return []

print(*pascal(10), sep='\n')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
[1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1]
[1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]
%
```